# SPList.OnQuickLaunch setting ignored

Tags: quick-launch

Using Sharepoint 2010 Foundation.
I have a number of custom list types I create in a feature. In the previous version, the types were visible on the quickLaunch by setting OnQuickLaunch = true  inside the EventReceiver.
In the new version we want to hide them. So I set OnQuickLaunch = false. However, the lists are still displayed on the QuickLaunch menu. 
Is there another setting I need to use to hide the custom lists from QuickLaunch programmatically?

Comment: Please **tag by feature** and not by version or product. This helps to attract more attention to your question and keep it relevant. See [How do I use tags](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264/) for general guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you do `SPList.Update()` after you set the OnQuickLaunch property to false.

Comment: Update is being called as well. Could be some other issue due to the feature having been deployed with QuickLaunch ON, and it stuck in the cache or somewhere else?

Comment: When you say EventReceiver do you mean FeatureReceiver? From the UI, go into List > List Settings > Title, description and navigation...Is Quick Launch set to Yes or No?  If Yes, does setting it to No and clicking Save hide the list?

Comment: I forgot to activate the feature...OOPS....